# Pixel values in a mosaic with TIFF images in Photoscan?

Tags: mosaic, geotiff-tiff, photogrammetry

I´m trying to understand how works the creation of a mosaic in photoscan or in other photogrammetry software.

When I use various TIFF images with information in their pixels (in my case temperatures) to make a mosaic, how the software works when stitch them?

Does it create an average of the value of same pixel in different images?

Obviously the temperature in same pixel in different images can´t be the same, because of that I need to know what the software do when stitch the images